# Hard resetting link, limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps

Tags: sata

Lenovo G500 laptop, Debian Jessie 8.7
Here is my dmesg output:

```
[22957.061286] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[22957.061294] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[22957.061297] ata3: SError: { DevExch }
[22957.061308] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[22957.061313] ata3: hard resetting link
[22957.784297] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[22957.784314] ata3: EH complete
[22957.784516] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[22957.784523] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[22957.784526] ata3: SError: { DevExch }
[22957.784537] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[22957.784541] ata3: hard resetting link
[22958.508901] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[22958.508918] ata3: EH complete
[22958.518360] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[22958.518368] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[22958.518371] ata3: SError: { DevExch }
[22958.518382] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[22958.518387] ata3: hard resetting link
[22959.241529] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[22959.241545] ata3: EH complete
[22959.241579] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[22959.241582] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[22959.241585] ata3: SError: { DevExch }
[22959.241594] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[22959.241597] ata3: hard resetting link
[22959.966135] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[22959.966153] ata3: EH complete
[22959.975493] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[22959.975500] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[22959.975504] ata3: SError: { DevExch }
[22959.975515] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[22959.975520] ata3: hard resetting link
[22960.698757] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[22960.698776] ata3: EH complete
[22960.709293] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[22960.709300] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[22960.709304] ata3: SError: { DevExch }
[22960.709315] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[22960.709319] ata3: hard resetting link
```

I get this message every second. Can someone exactly say what is the problem for this error codes?

Comment: Your hard disk is most likely failing.

Comment: I think the real issue here is a faulty cable.

Comment: @batistuta09 There isn't cable here, only a sata connector: [see picture](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/images/Lenovo-G570/upgrade-laptop-04.jpg)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen smartctl test completed without errors. Hard disk seems OK.

Comment: I have same thing on G510 Ubuntu 16.04. This had been happening for last 3-4 years with three different hard drives. (Linux seems to be able to cap the speed and work without problems, apart from showing that error message). BTW It freezes windows (by overloading disk queue). Probably connection between drive and motherboard. G510 doesn't have cable, it simply plugs into SATA socket (I just stopped using windows ;) )

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a faulty cable. I had the same issue, replaced the SATA cable and the error disappeared.